# AWS Lex: No option to create follow up prompt on Console

Tags: aws-lambda, bots, aws-lex

I am trying to create a follow up prompt (next response from the bot) in the console itself and not using Lambda functions. when I click on an option from the list of response cards.

[image]

In the above image, when I click 'color2', the next response (as a text or as a list of response cards) from the bot should be 'list of products in red are: a,b,c' (or a,b,c as prompts). I see no option on the console to set up an action for the button.

The response in the console is as below:

```
 {
  "dialogState": "ElicitIntent",
  "intentName": null,
  "message": "Sorry, can you please repeat that?",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": null
}
```

Comment: Could you include your Intents and Slots set up? I suspect you are fulfilling and closing the intent with the reply about colors. So Lex is trying to match the next input to another intent, not the same one. You should have a slot for colors, then a slot for products in the same intent. I highly recommend using Lambda to give you much more control. IMHO, the console alone is really only good for a simple FAQ.

Comment: @JayA.Little I did find examples where we can create custom functions using Lambda. But I have just started to explore features in Lex and would try to have a simple Q&A bot running for now. While the documentation mentions we can create a 'follow-up' prompt, I was curious to know if the console had a feature.

Comment: Maybe define 'follow-up' prompt? From how you describe the problem, it sounds like you just want Lex to ask QuestionA (colors), user clicks the button, Lex records that, then asks QuestionB (products), and the products will display based on the color selection. Now that is more complicated than a simple Q&A, and you will need Lambda to do it. A simple Q&A is one user question, one bot answer, next unrelated question, bot recognizes and answers new question. Basically, your bot is doing that now, and is trying to match the color input as a new question (tries to find a new intent to trigger).

Comment: Happy to give you an answer, but I would need to see your bot set up, a screenshot of your Intents and Slots would be enough, and I could help get you on the right track.